# How to remove an object from a list

Tags: java, list, object, equals

In Java, we can remove an object from a list by using the method list.remove(Object o), this method uses the equals method of the object to identify the element in the list. But, this requires us to override the equals method(otherwise the default implementation of the equals method would be used, which involves comparing the references). But if we are dealing with a list of objects and the developer doesn't have the liberty to change the source code of the object to implement the equals method, what can we do? I am wondering why java has not provided a method like list.remove(Object o, Comparator c), because then we could remove the object based on custom equality condition(implemented by the comparator), any solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want anything more complicated, you can always iterate yourself, performing any comparisons you want, and then use [`List.remove(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28int%29) to remove by index.

Comment: this is complicated, if I have, for example three objects to remove, then I would have to loop through very carefully and remove, because every time I remove an object, the size of the list decreases and hence if I am using a for loop(which iterates till the initial size of the list is reached) might give an exception (because there might be an attempt to remove an object on an index which is higher than the actual size)...this I would like to avoid

Comment: @Gaurav: The typical solution to that is to *either* check the size of the list each time (and decrement the index) or iterate from the end to the front.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a small framework for this:

Implement:

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/util/Matcher.html

Then use:

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/docs/api/org/softsmithy/lib/util/Matchers.html

The library is Open Source and can be downloaded from here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/softsmithy/files/softsmithy/v0.1/

Or with Maven:

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.softsmithy.lib</groupId>  
    <artifactId>lib-core</artifactId>  
    <version>0.1</version>  
</dependency>
```